# Passing media player object between activities

Tags: android

I wanted to know how to pass a MediaPlayer object between activities so that I can maintain a constant sound play through out the application.

Comment: Did you try the application class? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html You can put your object there and use it from your activities

Answer (score 3):

You don't "pass a `MediaPlayer` object between activities".

You need to access `MediaPlayer` from a custom [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to play sound in the background, and have your activities interact with this service.

For interaction my personal preference is binding using [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html). Whenever I tried to use simple intents and `onStartCommand`() it revealed insufficient for activity/service interaction (I work with audio too). But it could work for you.

With AIDL and binding, you could expose custom functions such as `play(uri)`, `pause()`, `rewind()`, etc.... The `MediaPlayer` instance would be created in `play(uri)` if it isn't already instantiated, and released in your service's `onDestroy()`.

You can even register a listener with a `RemoteCallbackList` to get notified about position changes or some other events. See the examples on the AIDL documentation. What's nice about this is that your service can detect when a listener unregisters. This way you can have a small timeout in the service before you call `stopSelf()`, if another listener (activity) doesn't register quickly. That's useful because you don't necessarily know if an activity pauses because the user pressed the home button, or because he's cycling from one activity to the other.

Yeah, it needs a little work ;)

Note: you still need to call `startService()` before binding, otherwise the service will stop whenever an activity unbinds.

Comment: According to what I read using MediaPlayer object will play the music using an asynchronous service automatically without interrupting the main thread.

Comment: Okay. Where in the service I should create the object and whether I should bind to the service or just start the service from the activities.

Comment: @Phalu...take this person's advice, it's 100% correct.  You don't really pass anything from activity to activity.

Comment: You are right, it is asynchronous. But it is operated by your activity. And an activity isn't supposed to do anything in the background. Here that means that it should stop playback when it gets paused. Maybe that you could assign the MediaPlayer object to a static variable, but that may result in memory leaks and other strange things.

Comment: So you ppl mean I should start the media playback when the current activity starts and stop it whenever the activity stops. So I need to do start and stop in all the activities. This would not make the media playback continuous!!!

Comment: No that's not what I mean. I have updated the answer about activity/service interaction. One activity can request the service to start playback, then another activity can request pausing. What I was saying in the comment is how it works when you don't use a service.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I would try the aidl. I'm not sure whether I can understand it. But first I'll try using simple local service as I don't need to create a thread.

Comment: You're welcome. I've very familiar with AIDL and I find it very reliable and flexible. But if your needs are simple then maybe that you can avoid AIDL and rely on startService(), using intents with a few custom actions. That may be a bit limited but easier.

Answer (score 0):

Check below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3