# How to pass MediaPlayer object between different components

Tags: android

I have a service(not bound) which throws a notification at a particular time and starts playing audio using MediaPlayer object.I set a pending intent when the notification is swiped(or deleted) which started a broadcast receiver. Now i want the receiver to stop the audio, but i have trouble passing the object as I can't make the MediaPlayer object implement parcelable. I dont want to bind the service, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954686/passing-media-player-object-between-activities) question. Is there a way of passing the object?

```
Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
while (!(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) == current.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) &&
Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) == current.get(Calendar.MINUTE) &&

Integer.parseInt(parts[2]) == current.get(Calendar.SECOND))) 
{
current = Calendar.getInstance();
}
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(AlarmService.this, R.raw.angersextended);

mediaPlayer.start();

Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, NotifSwipeReceiver.class);

Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
Log.i("abc1", "beforeparcelable");
bundle.putParcelable("mp", (Parcelable) mediaPlayer);
//bundle.putSerializable("mp", (Serializable) mediaPlayer);

Log.i("abc1","afterparcelable");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmService.this, 0, intent, 0);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AlarmService.this);
mBuilder.setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent);
mBuilder.setContentTitle(time);
mBuilder.setContentText("Alarm" + String.valueOf(j));
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
Log.i("abc", String.valueOf(j)+"notif");
```

and here's the broadcast receiver

```
public static class NotifSwipeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MediaPlayer mp= (MediaPlayer) intent.getExtras().getParcelable("mp");
        mp.stop();
        //MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.angersextended);
        //if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    public NotifSwipeReceiver(){
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register broadcast receiver at runtime in your service and unregister it when service stops, so you don't have to pass MediaPlayer between components.

Comment: Didn't get you. How does registering dynamically allow the object to be used by the broadcast receiver?